# Get only 1 object from array with 2 similar objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see here I have an array of 2 objects which have the same name and other elements, instead of x,y. I'm trying to console log them, and it works just fine, am getting 2 objects. My question is, how do I console.log only one of them, the first one?

```js
var _hero = [{
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}, {
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 15,
  y: 15
}]
let main = () => {
  _hero.forEach(function(_hero) {
    if (_hero.nick == "Mike") {
      console.log(_hero);
    }
  });
};
main();
```

Comment: umm ..  ```console.log(_hero[0])```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`array.find`** that will give you only the first matching element

```js
var _hero = [{
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}, {
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 15,
  y: 15
}]

console.log(_hero.find(data=>data.nick ==='Mike'));
```

Comment: There was a solution, using foreach method the asker asked

Answer (score 1):

Use second parameter in `forEach(function(hero, i){...` to check the iteration like the following:

```js
var _hero = [{
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}, {
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 15,
  y: 15
}]
let main = () => {
  _hero.forEach(function(_hero,i) {
    if (_hero.nick == "Mike" && i == 0) {
      console.log(_hero);
    }
  });
};
main();
```

Comment: So simple, damn! Thanks! :)

Comment: If you're doing that, what's the point in even using a loop? `console.log(_hero[0]);`

Comment: @nullqube: You can't stop a `forEach` loop.

Comment: @fubar, I have only used OP's code. He might need some other logic to implement on some other iteration.

Comment: @Mamun, but this foreach: 1) will not work if first object in array has another nick (more than 2 objects in array, in different order -> 'Mike' is not first) 2) if there are just two objects are in array, no need for loop at all, right? :)